# Load Records using the ADODB Connection with Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

So i have here my codes for fetching informations from the database using
the listview, and now i want to use the datagridview but i dont know how
to do it using the ADODB Connection[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbKLa.png).

Comment: See [ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/) - [Retrieving and Modifying Data in ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-and-modifying-data) - [Connecting to a Data Source in ADO.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connecting-to-a-data-source) -- You need to post code as text, not images of it.

Comment: You really shouldn't be using ADODB in VB.NET. Is there a specific reason you're doing so or was it just the default because you didn't know any better?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use an Odbc connection instead try this to retreive your data

```
Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("path to your database")
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand                                                                                       
Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim sql as String
Sql = "your SQL Query"             
conn.Open()
    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = Sql
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Odbc Connection in VB.Net.

First add new Module named `Connection.vb`

```
Imports System.Data.Odbc

Module Connection
    Public Con As New OdbcConnection
    Public Adpt As New OdbcDataAdapter
    Public Ds As New DataSet
    Public Cmd As OdbcCommand
    Public Read As OdbcDataReader
    Public Sql As String
    Public StrCon As String = "Dsn=Your DSN Name in Odbc Connector"

    Public Sub Connect()
        Con = New OdbcConnection(StrCon)

        If Con.State <> ConnectionState.Closed Then Con.Close()
        Con.Open()
    End Sub
End Module
```

And next don't forget to add `Imports System.Data.Odbc` in every form you have to connect to your Odbc Connection.

Simple Code to add item on ComboBox from Database.

```
Call Connect()

        Cmd = New OdbcCommand("SELECT * FROM `category` ", Con)

        cmbKategori.Items.Clear()
        cmbKategori.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Clear()

        Read = Cmd.ExecuteReader()
        If Read.HasRows = True Then
            While Read.Read()
                cmbKategori.AutoCompleteCustomSource.Add(Read("name_category"))
                cmbKategori.Items.Add(Read("name_category"))
            End While
        End If
```